# iOS 8 TableView overlaps rows after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, ios8

Only on iOS 8 and when scrolling do my rows overlap each other.  I tried the fixes for similar topics related to iOS 7 but I haven't solved my issue.  Please see attached image and my UITableView GetCell method.  I'm using MonoTouch but the logic is the same as objective-c.

[image]

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = null;
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CELL);

            if (cell == null)
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CELL);

            if (cell.ContentView.Subviews.Length > 0)
                cell.ContentView.Subviews[0].RemoveFromSuperview();

            UIView backgroundView = new UIView();
            cell.SelectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;

            if (list[indexPath.Row] != null)
            {
                cell.ContentView.AddSubview(list[indexPath.Row].View);
            }
            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: if (cell.ContentView.Subviews.Length > 0) why do u need this if function?

Comment: Good question.  Another developer put that in.  I would guess just a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

That might be one of the many senseless bugs from building on Xcode 6. Try this on the viewDidLoad function:

```
YourTableView.rowHeight = ##; //write your desired height.
```

if this doesn't work also try implementing the heightForRowAtIndexPath function for your tableview:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ##; //write your desired height
}
```

Comment: No go unfortunately.  The rows still overlap when scrolled up and down.

Comment: You can try deleting the tableview, putting it back and re-hook all the connections. This might solve it if the above answer didnt work.

Comment: No go.  I deleted and re-added a new table view but I get the same issue.  Everything is laid out perfect until I scroll out of view and back into view.