# UITableView overlaps cells after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, scroll, overlap

All, I have a UITableView to which I add cells on user input. My cells have a slight transparency, and I recently noticed that after I have more cells than fit the screen, when I scroll down and back up, the cells which were momentarily off-screen **now have new cells positioned behind them!**

This shows up in my app, and also is evidenced in the view hierarchy debugger. [image: With two cells overlapping][image: With all cells overlapping]

Interesting to note that it only happens when two or more cells scroll off screen (notice the count skips cell 7, which is at the bottom, just off the screen at the moment.

I figure this has something to do with caching the UIScrollView data for quicker loads? How do I stop it?

**Adding a cell:**

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfCounters inSection:0], nil];
[counterTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

numberOfCounters++;
[counters addObject:[[CKCounter alloc] init]];
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath: method**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CKCounter";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    CKCounter *counter = [counters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [counter setCurrentCount:indexPath.row];
    [counter setIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[counter view]];
    [cell.contentView setAutoresizesSubviews:TRUE];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    /** Sets up the bounds for the subcounters **/
    CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    frame.size.height -= counterMargins;                                                            // This will give the counters an inset
    frame.size.width  -= counterMargins;                                                            // The gap will be split to each side
    frame.origin = cell.contentView.bounds.origin;
    counter.view.frame = frame;
    counter.view.opaque = false;
    counter.view.center = cell.contentView.center;

    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[indexPath indexAtPosition:0]]
    return cell;
}
```

See also: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007184/ios-8-tableview-overlaps-rows-after-scrolling)

Comment: Show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath, and for how you're adding the new cells.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your problem, but when you scroll, you'll be adding new instances of CKCounterView to your cells with [cell.contentView addSubview:[counter view]] (unless you're deleting the old ones somewhere).

Comment: @rdelmar Really? I did that under the impression that 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' was only called once at tableView instantiation? What is the proper way to create cells and load their subviews once, and not have this add new cells?

Comment: - What I just did was put all of my creation code into the if (cell == nil) block? It seemed to work but then it would stop creating new cells after the screen was filled, and it would start reusing the same objects for the next cells...

Comment: Yeah, that's the way it works -- the system only creates enough cells that it needs to show at once, then it reuses them. The best way to add subviews, if you want to do it in code, is to add any subviews in the init method of your custom cell class. Otherwise just make the cell in a storyboard or nib.